# Error in hist.default(OBJECTNAME$COLUMNNAME) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, csv, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram in R (of given values in a column from a given CSV file) Hence I used:

```
read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE) -> temp
```

which open a file browser and allows me to choose a file and save its content in an object "temp". Then I used,

```
hist (temp$Sex)
```

Where Sex is the column name & what I get is a error message like this:

> **Error in hist.default(temp$Sex) : 'x' must be numeric**

Could any one help me plot values of a column in a graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your temp$Sex column only contains "m" and "f" you could try the following:

```
barplot(table(temp$Sex))
```